# Responsive menu not opening on 320px screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement this (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) script for a responsive menu. I followed all the steps and used the proper code, but the menu won't open in a 320px screen width. Can anyone give me a heads up on how to fix this? FYI: I'm a newby in scripting.

Thanks a lot!

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class='clearfix'>  
        <ul class='clearfix'> 
            <li><a href="#seapr">Sea PR?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#seaprvoor">Sea PR voor...</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#pr">Press Relations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#copywriting">Copywriting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#websites">Websites</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>  
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, `pull` is already a jQuery object. No need for `$(pull)`.

Comment: You should consider media queries http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

you may want to remove this:

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
```

and replace it with

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
            if(menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
```

Comment: I guess it is a combination of Pete's and Felix's answer. The code you used disables the menu for small screen widths, probably to not overlap the content (`w > 320`).

Comment: I tried Pete's and Felix' solution and a combination of both, but none could get it to work.

Comment: @user3198145 try updating your version of jQuery to 1.10.1 and also if you have a look at your js console, does it show any errors?

Comment: @user3198145 that is because you are using jQuery 1.10.1 in your fiddle but 1.7.2 in your code above - is there any reason for using the older version of jQuery?

Comment: I took it over from the original code. I replaced it with jQuery 1.10.1 on my testpage, but it still has te same result.

Comment: if you view the source for the page, have you included any other js libraries or files and did you check if your js console was showing any errors? if you put an alert into the `$(pull).on('click', function(e) {` does it fire?

Answer (score 1):

After go through the source of your demo site, it's turn out that you haven't included the `nav.js` file:

```
<script src="http://demo.hongkiat.com/_nav/js/nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```